# Readonly items in ical iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, icalendar

I need to display some events on the iphone calendar from either a local app or possibly a remote server. I need the events shown in the iphone calendar to be readonly and am trying to figure out the best approach for this. Couple of questions to help me with the approach

-From ios iphone app can I write calendar events as readonly?
-If I need to go from the server to the phone can I give the phone a url to a icalendar that is readonly? which will disallow updates to the item on the phone?
-If I consume the events from the icalendar in to an iphone application can I tell what the origin of the item is? meaning can I tell the difference between things the user made locally, exchange, gmail etc.. and the icalendar readonly feed

Thanks

Comment: Upvoting for interesting, though I don't think its very user friendly to create item's in their calendar that they do not have full control over.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote! My use case is pretty solid and have run in to it on 2 projects. We have an event inside an app that is tied to a lot more logic than just time, date, desc. We have chained events that are triggered by the scheduling or completion of other items. Allowing 3rd party control here get tough because when I get back the calendar item in the app it might have been altered because the user didn't know any better. I recognize that the ical is a great tool for solving "What do I need to do and when" which is why we don't want to force users only into our app for event info.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you cannot create a read-only calendar entry in a users calendar. After all, it's the **users** calendar, not your apps.

Nor can you create a separate calendar specific for your app that can read from a URL. You could provide the URL to the user and ask them to add it to iCal manually, but you cannot do it via the EventKit Framework.

You can't tell the origin of an event as `EKEvent` doesn't have any sort of public property that provides this information.

You would be able to infer which was the read-only calendar by iterating over the available calenders and looking at their titles. However, this would only work on the assumptions the user actually added your calendar manually, and they didn't change the title.

The best way to do something like this with all the features you want would be to add in-app calendar functionality to your app and make it completely independent of iCal and EventKit.

Here are a couple of projects which could help ...

- [Kal](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal)
- [Calendar UI](https://github.com/muhku/calendar-ui)